# Tab visible on form save action in yii

Tags: yii, tabs

How can i make the CTabview visible on form create/save action in Yii?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IN your form where you have this button. wrap it inside **if()**
eg:-

```
<?php if($model->isNewRecord): ?>
// your button code
<?php endif; ?>
```